# Proving a weaker version of the Jordan Curve Theorem (by induction)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, simplicial-complex

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Suppose that the sphere $ \mathbb{S}^2 $
>   is given the structure of a closed combinatorial surface.
>   Let $C$ be a subcomplex that is a simplicial circle. Suppose that $ \mathbb{S}^2\backslash C$
>   has two components. Indeed,
>   suppose that this is true for every simplicial circle in $ \mathbb{S}^2
> $
>   . Let $E$ be one of these components.
>
> The aim is to show that $\bar{E}$ is homeomorphic to a disc. Prove this statement by induction on the number of 2-simplices in $\bar{E}$.
>
> **(1)**: Let $\sigma _1$ be a 1-simplex in $C$ . Since $\mathbb{S}^2$
>   is a closed combinatorial surface, $\sigma _1$ is adjacent to two
>   2-simplices. Show that precisely one of these 2-simplices lies in $\bar{E}$.
>
> **(2)**: Start the induction by showing that if $\bar{E}$ contains at most one 2-simplex, then $\bar{E}=\sigma_2$
>
> **(3)**:  Let $v$ be the vertex of $\sigma_2$ not lying in $\sigma_1$. Let’s suppose that $v$ does not lie in $C$ . Show how
>   to construct a subcomplex $C'$ of $\mathbb{S}^2$
>   , that is a simplicial circle, and that has the following
>   properties:
>
> - $\mathbb{S}^2\backslash C'$ has two components
> - one of these two components $F$ is a subset of $E$
> - $\bar{F}$ has fewer 2-simplices than $\bar{E}$
>
> Show in this case that $\bar{E}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2$, with the homeomorphism taking $C$ to $\partial\mathbb{D}^2.$
>
> **(4)**: Suppose now that $v$ lies in $C$. How do we complete the proof in this case?

I've managed to complete the first three parts, but am now stuck on (4).

I know you can work your way round the 1-simplices in $C$ using each in place of $\sigma _1$ in turn, and if you come across one where it's associated $v$ is not in $C$ then just apply the result from (3).

Surely though it would be possible that the corresponding 2-simplex for each 1-simplex in $C$ had it's third vertex in $C$ - how else would you show it's homeomorphic, because I can't thing of a way to make the same trick work?

I'd really appreciate any help you could offer!

Comment: Just a remark on names: The *Jordan Curve Theorem* is the statement that $\mathbb S^2 \setminus C$ has two components, which is not what you are trying to prove. Instead, you are trying to prove the *Schönflies Theorem*, which is the statement that the closure of each component of $\mathbb S^2 \setminus C$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to prove the following by induction:

Let $C$ be a simplicial circle in $S^2$. If $E$ is a component of $S^2 \setminus C$ such that the number of $2$-simplices in $\overline{E}$ is at most $n$, then $\overline{E}$ is homeomorphic to a disc.

Obviously $n=0$ is impossible. The case $n=1$ has been considered in your question.

Now let us consider the case that that the number of $2$-simplices in $\overline{E}$ is $n+1$, where $n \ge 1$.

We take a $1$-simplex $\sigma_1 = (v_1,v_2)$ in $C$ and consider the unique $2$-simplex $\sigma_2 = (v_1,v_2,v)$ belonging to $\overline{E}$ which exists by (1). The case that $v$ is not in $C$ has been settled and you ask what happens if $v$ is in $C$.

Since $C$ is a simplicial
circle, we can arrange its $1$-simplices in a chain $\sigma^1_1,\dots,\sigma^m_1$ beginning an ending at $v_1$ such that $\sigma^1_1 = \sigma_1$. There is one $\sigma^i_1$ ending at $v$. We get two simplicial circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ given by $(v,v_1), \sigma^1_1,\dots,\sigma^i_1$ and $\sigma^{i+1}_1,\dots,\sigma^m_1,(v_1,v)$. They have the following properties:

- $S^2\setminus C_k$ has two components
- one of these two components $F_k$ is a subset of $E$
- $\bar{F}_k$ has fewer 2-simplices than $\bar{E}$, i.e. at most $n$

Hence $\bar{F}_k$ are (simplicial) discs and we have $\bar{F}_1 \cup \bar{F}_2 = \bar{E}$. $\bar{F}_1$ and $\bar{F}_2$ intersect in a $1$-simplex lying in the boundaries of both. It is then easy to show that their union is a homeomorphic to a disc.